# Can MMU function be emulated in software or is the MMU chip necessary for a processor to support virtual memory?

Tags: memory, memory-management, emulation, virtual-memory, mmu

Can MMU function be emulated in software or is the MMU chip necessary for a processor to support virtual memory?

Does such an emulation exist? Is the performance impact big?

Comment: By "MMU chip" do you include on-die address translations, as found on e.g. all Intel processors from this century?

Comment: @Caleth to be honest I do not know about the Intel implementation of this function. I do not how does Intel does the address translation on-die and how does this differ from traditional MMU chips and function. Is it like an embedded MMU ?

Answer (score 0):

It could be emulated in software. The problem is that it would be painfully slow. There would likely be an exception for every memory access.